# Sklearn kmeans with multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, k-means

I can't understand how the n_jobs works :

```
data, labels = sklearn.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=416, centers=20)
k_means = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=10, max_iter=3, n_jobs=1).fit(data)
```

runs in less than 1sec

with n_jobs = 2, it runs nearly twice as much

with n_jobs = 8, it is so long it never ended on my computer... (I have 8 cores)

Is there something I don't understand with how parallelization works ?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/why-using-more-threads-makes-it-slower-than-using-less-threads

Comment: well.. not really because I have 8 cpu cores so it is not the issue. Can you reproduce this issue, or is this only on my computer ?

Comment: what is you skearn and joblib versions?

Comment: The code above is working normally (completes in under 1 sec) for each value of n_jobs between 1 to 8. I have 4 cores. I am using latest version of scikit-learn on python 3.6. You need to check your versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n_jobs` specifies the number of concurrent processes/threads should be used for parallelized routines

From [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs)

> Some parallelism uses a multi-threading backend by default, some a
>   multi-processing backend. It is possible to override the default backend by using sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.

With python GIL, more threads does not guarantee better speed. So check if your backend is configured for threads or processes. If it is threads then try changing it to processes (but you will also have the overhead of IPC).

Again from the docs:

> Whether parallel processing is helpful at improving runtime depends on
>   many factors, and it’s usually a good idea to experiment rather than
>   assuming that increasing the number of jobs is always a good thing. It
>   can be highly detrimental to performance to run multiple copies of
>   some estimators or functions in parallel.

So `n_jobs` is not a silver bullet but one has to experiment to see if it works for their estimators and kind of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `n_jobs=-1` to use all your CPUs or `n_jobs=-2` to use all of them except one.

**Update**:
`n_jobs` parameter is deprecated since version 0.23 and removed in 1.0.
Apparently you can have the same functionality by setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable (in this case), like:

```bash
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 python my_script.py
```

Read more about parallelism here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/parallelism.html#lower-level-parallelism-with-openmp

Comment: Scikit version 1.2.0 gives error: TypeError: k_means() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'